# Select rows that have columns equal values in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new user of `Laravel 5.2`

For example i have data rows something like this:

```
mytable
-------------------------------
url          |  ip         
-------------------------------
google.com   |  11.44.180.149       <----- 
msn.com      |  11.44.180.149 
google.com   |  11.44.180.149       <-----  
yahoo.com    |  11.44.180.149         
google.com   |  11.44.180.149       <-----
```

I want select all rows that 2 or 3 columns value their is equal and `delete` rows equal that it's more than one

For example convert to this:

```
mytable
-------------------------------
url          |  ip         
-------------------------------
google.com   |  11.44.180.149       <----- 
msn.com      |  11.44.180.149 
yahoo.com    |  11.44.180.149
```

Guys i'm so sorry because can't speak English very well.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just use a unique key across both columns so that only one entry can exist?

Comment: @Styphon because i have `created_at` column i need the all data for show reports and chart of table for 3 day ago or 1 week ago

Comment: I think what you're after is the `DISTINCT` keyword, try `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mytable`

Comment: Try gorupBy('ip')

Comment: @Styphon please answer complate i'm new user of `Laravel 5.2` i can't try  . please show me i can't understand your mean. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) method with Eloquent:

```
MyTable::groupBy('ip')->get();
```

Or query builder:

```
DB::table('mytable')->groupBy('ip')->get();
```

Comment: I tested your answer but it isn't select rows that url and ip is same, it give me all rows !!! I want give me just any rows that is equal value

Answer (score 0):

You need to first select the columns you want to check, then do a DISTINCT.

```
DB::table('mytable')->select('url','ip')->Distinct()->get();
```

This should only include one of each matching set.

Comment: I tested your answer but it isn't select  rows that `url` and `ip` is same, it give me all rows !!! I want give me just any rows that is equal values

Answer (score 0):

If you try this,

```
$myTable = MyTable::groupBy('url', 'ip')
                ->get(['url', 'ip']);
```

or

```
$myTable = DB::table('mytable')->groupBy('url', 'ip')
                ->get(['url', 'ip']);
```

Please check this code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $query = DB::table('MyTable');
     $query->whereIn('ip', function($query) {
            $query->select('ip')
                ->from('MyTable')
                ->groupBy('ip')
                 ->having(DB::raw('count(*)'),'>',1);
        });
         $user=$query->get();
         dd($user);
```